# Error when running make on Garfield++ install on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, cmake

In the process of installing Garfield++ on Ubuntu I was required to enter

```
cd $GARFIELD_HOME; make
```

when I got this error

> ```
>     Assembler messages:
> Fatal error: can't create /home/mydir/garfield/Object/ComponentTcad3d.o: Permission denied
> makefile:192: recipe for target '/home/mydir/garfield/Object/ComponentTcad3d.o' failed
> make: *** [/home/mydir/garfield/Object/ComponentTcad3d.o] Error 1
> ```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Is there a tutorial or procedure you're following that told you to enter that command?  Seeing all the steps you've done so far may help.

Comment: How does CMake relate with your problem? Note, that `CMake` != `make`.

Comment: Reply to Denis , Yes here it is [link](https://garfieldpp.web.cern.ch/garfieldpp/getting-started/)

Comment: Made the title refer more explicitly to question.

Answer (score 0):

`/home/mydir` is most likely owned by root. You should clone the repository in a folder that is owned by your user. For example, `$HOME/garfield` would be a good location.